# KDB+: get count of all substrings in a table of strings

Tags: select, count, substring, grouping, kdb

I'm new in KDB and struggling with creating a query. Will appreciate any help.

I have a table of strings and need to get the count of all specific substrings across all strings in the table.

So, let's assume that I have strings:

```
[ 
   string1: Apple is green, cherry is red, 
   string2: Ququmber is green, banana is yellow 
]
```

and I want to get a count of "Apple" and "green" across all substrings. My desired result is to have a grouping like so:

```
{ 
   Apple: 1, 
   green: 2 
}
```

But, unfortunately, I have no idea how to make such a grouping. I have already figured out how to get strings that contain at least one of the needed substrings:

```
"select count(text) from data where any text like/: (\"*$Apple*\";\"*$green*\")"
```

but that returns me the cumulative result of all found strings for Apple and green without any grouping:

```
{
    text: 3
}
```

which does not allow differentiating the amount of each particular substring.

I will be really thankful for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using a where clause with an `any`, you can put the `like/:` in the select phrase to get a nested list of booleans where each list represents the matches for one search string. Then you can just `sum` these to get the total matches for each search string. I've used an `exec` here rather than a `select` as I suspect that output will be more useful:

```
q)t:([] text:("Apple is green, cherry is red,";"Ququmber is green, banana is yellow"))
q)exec sum each text like/:("*Apple*";"*green*") from t
1 2i
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `-4!` to count the frequency of every substring

```
q)t:([] text:("Apple is green, cherry is red,";"Ququmber is green, banana is yellow"))
q)count each group exec raze -4!'text from t
"Apple"   | 1
," "      | 10
"is"      | 4
"green"   | 2
,","      | 3
"cherry"  | 1
"red"     | 1
"Ququmber"| 1
"banana"  | 1
"yellow"  | 1
```